# Style enumeration in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, enumerate

I am writing a journal and I am using the standard `enumitem` package for writing enumerated lists. The current list I am using is:

In the preamble

```
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
```

and in the document

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}.]
%code to executed here
\end{enumerate}
```

However, the team of the journal asked me to change this to the following:

**______________________**

Exercise XX

**______________________**

where XX is the counter e.g 1, 2, 3 ... and so on. I have no idea how to do this. The only thing that comes to mind is combining TIkZ with a self created enumerator. However, I cannot come up with the correct macros needed to do this.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `amsthm` since your exercises seemed a lot like the ones defined in the `amsthm` package. I invite you to read that documentation.

The pro is that you can style the thing pretty well and easily, the con is that you have an environment per example.

Here what I got:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{xca}{Exercise}
\newenvironment{myexercise}{%
\par\noindent \rule{4pc}{1pt}\begin{xca}}%
{\end{xca}\noindent\rule{4pc}{1pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{myexercise}
Test
\end{myexercise}
\end{document}
```

with this result:

[image]

These are the main lines:

- `\theoremstyle{definition}` uses the predefined style of amsthm
- `\newtheorem{xca}{Exercise}` sets up a new theorem (`xca`) in the aforementioned style, with title **Exercise**
- I then have to set up the rules, which I give as `\rule{4pc}{1pt}` since they seemed fine for me. They might need fine tuning
- The `\par\noindent` serve the purpose to end the previous paragraph and leave no indentation. The `noindent` is required after the environment too.

---

**EDIT**

Since OP needs something a bit different, i.e. a `\newline` after the title, I defined a new `theoremstyle` and applied it. `amsthm` documentation has it all explained

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{mydefinition}%
{3pt}% space above
{5pt}% space below
{}% body font
{}% indent
{\bfseries}% header font
{.} % header punctuation
{\newline}% after header space
{}%
\theoremstyle{mydefinition}
\newtheorem{xca}{Exercse}
\newenvironment{myexercise}{\par\noindent \rule{4pc}{1pt}\begin{xca}}{\end{xca}\noindent\rule{4pc}{1pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{myexercise}
Test
\end{myexercise}
\end{document}
```

With result:

[image]

**NOTE:** I put some dummy example for top and bottom separation, just to show that you can put "normal" dimensions there.

Comment: This is nice , however, and that's my bad for not having said it before but the exercise should be outside of that environment. That is text should be below the second line... Any clues for this?

Comment: @Tolaso you can style them as you want. I'm adding a new example

Comment: @Tolaso better now?

Answer (score 1):

This is another possibility, with `ntheorem`. I patched the `break` style to define a `ruled` style, and added a little treat with `microtype`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fourier, cabin}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{ruled}%
  {\hrule\qquad\item[[\indent\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
          ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}] \leavevmode\vspace*{-1.3ex}\hrule\vspace{2ex}}%
  {\hrule\item[\indent\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
          ##1\ ##2\ (##3)\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}] \leavevmode\vspace*{-1.3ex}\hrule\vspace{2ex}}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{ruled}%
\theoremheaderfont{\lsstyle\sffamily\scshape}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}[An exciting exercise]
 Prove that equality is an equivalence relation.
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]